# passing the parameters of sp_executesql to sp_ineachdb or sp_foreachdb

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql, scripting

I am often in need to run the [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) [in the context of different databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/232443/22336)

I would like to add the same parameters as the [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) into the [sp_ineachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/)

But when I look at this:
-- Syntax for SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, Parallel Data Warehouse

> sp_executesql [ @stmt = ] statement   [      { , [ @params = ]
>   N'@parameter_name data_type [ OUT | OUTPUT ][ ,...n ]' }
>        { , [ @param1 = ] 'value1' [ ,...n ] }   ]

I can't find out how to define all the parameters to add to the `sp_ineachdb`.

For example the code below checks for an index inside a database:

```
    declare @IndexName NVARCHAR(128)='si_xdes_id'
    declare @dbname NVARCHAR(128) = db_name()
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @retval INT  

IF @IndexName IS NOT NULL /*validate the index exists in the @dbname database*/
   BEGIN

        SELECT @sql = 'SELECT @retvalOUT = CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                               SELECT * FROM ' + @dbname + '.sys.indexes I WHERE I.Name = @IndexName  ) 
                               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END '

        SET @ParamDefinition = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT,
                                @IndexName SYSNAME';

        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDefinition, @retvalOUT= @retval OUTPUT, @IndexName  = @IndexName;

        IF (@retval = 0) 
            BEGIN

               --RAISERROR('The index called %s does not exist on database %s',16,1,@IndexName,@dbname)
               RETURN

            END 
   END
```

for me to use it in conjunction with [sp_ineachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/) I have to wrap the whole thing into dynamic sql:

```
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)=

'   declare @IndexName NVARCHAR(128)=''uc_emailAddress''
    declare @dbname NVARCHAR(128) = db_name()
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @retval INT  

IF @IndexName IS NOT NULL /*validate the index exists in the @dbname database*/
   BEGIN

        SELECT @sql = ''SELECT @retvalOUT = CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                               SELECT * FROM '' + @dbname + ''.sys.indexes I WHERE I.Name = @IndexName  ) 
                               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ''

        SET @ParamDefinition = N''@retvalOUT int OUTPUT,
                                @IndexName SYSNAME'';

        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDefinition, @retvalOUT= @retval OUTPUT, @IndexName  = @IndexName;

        select @dbname,@retval

        IF (@retval = 0) 
            BEGIN

               --RAISERROR(''The index called %s does not exist on database %s'',16,1,@IndexName,@dbname)
               RETURN

            END 
   END
'

if object_id('tempdb..#radhe') is not null
   drop table #radhe
create table #radhe(dbname sysname, the_index_exist_here int)
insert into #radhe
EXEC sp_ineachdb @command = @sql, @user_only = 1;

select * from #radhe
```

which gives me:

[image]

question:

is there any easier way to get this done?

I would like to pass to [sp_ineachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/)  all the parameters that I currently pass to [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and just gracefully collect the output.

Is that any possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `sp_ineachdb` was not designed with this specific use case in mind (nested dynamic SQL with parameters), and I don't know if you can do all you want to do with this script without any dynamic SQL at all. I think this approach will be a bit simpler - you'll have to call `sp_ineachdb` twice, but the dynamic SQL portion is much, much simpler, and you won't have to relay parameters for the procedure to in turn pass along to its own internal `sp_executesql` call.

```
DECLARE @indexname nvarchar(128) = N'uc_emailAddress',
        @cmd       nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT db = DB_NAME(),0;';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #radhe;    

CREATE TABLE #radhe
(
  dbname sysname, 
  indexname nvarchar(128), 
  the_index_exist_here bit
);

INSERT #radhe(dbname,the_index_exist_here)
EXEC master.dbo.sp_ineachdb @command = @cmd, @user_only = 1;

UPDATE #radhe SET indexname = @indexname;

SET @cmd = N'UPDATE r SET the_index_exist_here = 1
    FROM #radhe AS r
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i
    ON r.dbname = DB_NAME()
    AND i.name = r.indexname;';

EXEC master.dbo.sp_ineachdb @cmd;

SELECT dbname, the_index_exist_here FROM #radhe;
```